# Lucene: Cant return any hits from lucene index when document is indexed successfully

Tags: java, eclipse, lucene

I want to store and return Lucene document with a method so i can use it in another application.

I have two methods in my class file:
1. `resultSet` method which returns an array of `Document` objects of the search result.
With code below:

```
public Document[] resultSet() throws IOException, Exception{
        /********** HERE WE DO MAJOR PROCESSING CALL OF THE WRITER AND SEEARCHER ************/
        TopDocs hits = null;
        System.out.println("Am ahere");
        // We set array of the document we returned
        Document[] resultSet={};
        // PROCESSING THE SEARCH FILES
        // Before we process the index searcher we check
        // The content of the docPath
        if(docPath!=null && docPath.length()>4){
        // PROCESSING THE INDEX WRITER
        // Before we process the index writer we check
        // The content of the indexPath
        if(indexPath.length()>4 && indexPath!=null){ // Ensuring its a path or directory string
        // Lets check if we have instruction to index or not
        if(nio==1){
        IndexFiles indexFile=new IndexFiles(indexPath, docPath, xfields, create);
        // Here we get all Index File parameters and log it to our process logger method
        indexStart=indexFile.start; // index Start Date
        indexEnd=indexFile.end; // index End Date
        message=indexFile.message; // Message log
        // LETS CLOSE INDEXER
        indexFile.close();
        } // End of index option check
        }
        // NOW LETS CALL THE SEARCH FILES CLASS TO INSTANTIATE IT
        searchStart=new Date(); // Search Start Date
        SearchFiles searches=new SearchFiles(indexPath, toParam);
        searchEnd=new Date(); // Search End Date
        // BufferedReader
        BufferedReader in = null;
        boolean checkQ=false;
        // Lets check if query is a file
        File cfile=new File(queryX);
        // Now lets check
        if(cfile.isFile()){
        // We process queryX as a file
        in = Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(queryX), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        checkQ=true;
        }
        else{
        checkQ=false;
        }


        // Here we are going to select the data we use for line
        String line = checkQ != true ? queryX : in.readLine();
        // Now lets trim the line

        line = line.trim();

        // Now lets search the index
        hits=searches.search(line);
        // NOW LETS GET THE TOTAL HITS
        totalHits=hits.totalHits;

        /*************** WE TRY TO PROCESS HITS INTO DOCUMENTS ***************/
        ScoreDoc[] searched=searchFetched(hits);
        int increment=0;
        // Now we call the Document to get document
        for(ScoreDoc scoreDoc:searched){
        // Get document 
        Document doc=searches.getDocument(scoreDoc);
        // Now lets add to resultset
        resultSet[increment]=doc;
        increment++;
        } // End of loop

        // LETS CLOSE THE SEARCHER
        searches.close();
        // End of DocPath Check
        }

        // NOW LETS RETURN THE HITS
        return resultSet;

     // End of method     
    }
```

2. `searchFetched` which returns `ScoreDocs` that is used by `resultSet` method:

   ```
   private ScoreDoc[] searchFetched(TopDocs hits) throws IOException, Exception{
   // Lets set the array to hold our scores

   // NOW LETS RETURN SCORES
   return hits.scoreDocs;
   ```

   }

This is my main method were I tried to display the output of the returned document stored in an array:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
            /***** HERE WE PROCESS THE METHODS IN THE CLASS ********/
            // Setting Object Variables
            String xFiles="{indexDir:cores/core/testData/indexdir,docDir:cores/core/testData/datadir,nio:1}";
            String xParams="{update:false,xfields:sender*receiver*subject,queryX:Job openings,[f>subject-h>10-m>100-n>0-r>true]}";
            // Setting new constructor of this method
            SearchHandle handles=new SearchHandle(xFiles, xParams);
            // Now we can call other methods in the Search handler class
            try {
                // Now lets fetch data
                Document[] rows=handles.resultSet();
                System.out.println(Arrays.toString(rows));
                System.out.println(handles.totalHits);
                // Now we can loop to display the result of the searched
                for(Document row:rows){
                    // Now we make use of scoreDoc
                    System.out.println("File: " +row.get("path"));
                } // End of loop
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

`Am no more getting error, the problem now is that am not getting any hits even when the document are indexed.
I also found writer.lock in the index directory. What could be the cause of zero hits`

**Edit With Current Result**
Am no more getting error. My indexFile works and its indexing documents.
The problem is that i cant get any hits when i search the indexed document.
This is my `indexFile Code`:

```
package com.***.***.handlers.searchHandler;


import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.nio.file.FileVisitResult;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.SimpleFileVisitor;
import java.nio.file.attribute.BasicFileAttributes;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
import java.util.*;

import org.apache.lucene.analysis.Analyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.analysis.standard.StandardAnalyzer;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Document;
import org.apache.lucene.document.Field;
import org.apache.lucene.document.LongPoint;
import org.apache.lucene.document.StringField;
import org.apache.lucene.document.TextField;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriter;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig;
import org.apache.lucene.index.IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode;
import org.apache.lucene.index.Term;
import org.apache.lucene.store.Directory;
import org.apache.lucene.store.FSDirectory;

/** Index all text files under a directory.
 *
 * This is a universal text index java application that can be used on Djade 
 * And other software related application 
 */
public class IndexFiles {
  // Creating public variables to use
    public Date start;
    public Date end;
    public String message="";
    private IndexWriter writer;
    private static String docType;
 // Now Construct the class 
  public IndexFiles(String indexPath, String xdocs, String xfields, boolean create) {

      // Lets declare local variable
      String docsPath="";
      String xType="";
      String xValues="";
      /************ HERE WE PROCESS THE XDOCS STRING TO KNOW THE TYPE OF DATA **********/
      String[] xArray=xdocs.split("@");
      // Lets get count
      int xCount=xArray.length;
      // NOW LETS CHECK COUNT TO LOOP
      if(xCount>0){
          // We the assign values to each and check
          xType=xArray[0];
          xValues=xArray[1];
          // Now We assign file string to the docsPath
          docsPath=xValues;
          // Now we check Xtype value to assign type appropriately
          if(xType.equals(new String("as"))){
              // We set type to array String
              docType="arrayFile";
          }
          else if(xType.equals(new String("of"))){
             // We set type to normal file
              docType="normalFile";
          }
      } // End of count check

        final Path docDir = Paths.get(docsPath);
        if (!Files.isReadable(docDir)) {
            message+="Document directory '" +docDir.toAbsolutePath()+ "' does not exist or is not readable, please check the path \n";
          System.exit(1);
        }

        start = new Date();
        try {
            message+="Indexing to directory '" + indexPath + "'... \n";

          Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(Paths.get(indexPath));
          Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer();
          IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(analyzer);

          if (create) {
            // Create a new index in the directory, removing any
            // previously indexed documents:
            iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE);
          } else {
            // Add new documents to an existing index:
            iwc.setOpenMode(OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
          }

          // Optional: for better indexing performance, if you
          // are indexing many documents, increase the RAM
          // buffer.  But if you do this, increase the max heap
          // size to the JVM (eg add -Xmx512m or -Xmx1g):
          //
          // iwc.setRAMBufferSizeMB(256.0);

          writer = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc);
          indexDocs(writer, docDir, xfields);

          // NOTE: if you want to maximize search performance,
          // you can optionally call forceMerge here.  This can be
          // a terribly costly operation, so generally it's only
          // worth it when your index is relatively static (ie
          // you're done adding documents to it):
          //
          // writer.forceMerge(1);


          end = new Date();
          message+=end.getTime() - start.getTime() + " total milliseconds \n";

        } catch (IOException e) {
            message+=" caught a " + e.getClass() +
           "\n with message: " + e.getMessage()+" \n";
        }
  }

  /** Index all text files under a directory. */
  public void close() throws IOException{ 
      writer.close();
  }

  /**
   * Indexes the given file using the given writer, or if a directory is given,
   * recurses over files and directories found under the given directory.
   * 
   * NOTE: This method indexes one document per input file.  This is slow.  For good
   * throughput, put multiple documents into your input file(s).  An example of this is
   * in the benchmark module, which can create "line doc" files, one document per line,
   * using the
   * <a href="../../../../../contrib-benchmark/org/apache/lucene/benchmark/byTask/tasks/WriteLineDocTask.html"
   * >WriteLineDocTask</a>.
   *  
   * @param writer Writer to the index where the given file/dir info will be stored
   * @param path The file to index, or the directory to recurse into to find files to index
   * @throws IOException If there is a low-level I/O error
   * System.out.println(file);
   */
  static void indexDocs(final IndexWriter writer, Path path, String fields) throws IOException {
    if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
      Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
        @Override
        public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
          try {
            indexDoc(writer, file, fields, attrs.lastModifiedTime().toMillis());
          } catch (IOException ignore) {
            // don't index files that can't be read.
          }
          return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
        }
      });
    } else {
      indexDoc(writer, path, fields, Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toMillis());
    }
  }

  /** Indexes a single document */
  static void indexDoc(IndexWriter writer, Path file, String fields, long lastModified) throws IOException {
    try (InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(file)) {
      // make a new, empty document
      Document doc = new Document();
      // Creating a string array
      String[] contentArray = null;
      String[] prefixArray = null;
      // Array list variable
      List<String> prefixList=new ArrayList<String>();
      List<String> contentList=new ArrayList<String>();

      // Other variable parts
      String[] fieldArray;
      String[] fieldValidType={"pdf", "xml", "html"};
      String data="";
      BufferedReader fin = null;
      String fLine="";

      // Checking if field is string of a file
      File field=new File(fields);
      String meta="";
      String metaType="";
      String typeVal="";
      String[] metaData;
      String[] typeSplit;
      String ffields="";

      // Add the path of the file as a field named "path".  Use a
      // field that is indexed (i.e. searchable), but don't tokenize 
      // the field into separate words and don't index term frequency
      // or positional information:
      Field pathField = new StringField("path", file.toString(), Field.Store.YES);
      doc.add(pathField);

      // Add the last modified date of the file a field named "modified".
      // Use a LongPoint that is indexed (i.e. efficiently filterable with
      // PointRangeQuery).  This indexes to milli-second resolution, which
      // is often too fine.  You could instead create a number based on
      // year/month/day/hour/minutes/seconds, down the resolution you require.
      // For example the long value 2011021714 would mean
      // February 17, 2011, 2-3 PM. System.out.println(lastModified);
      doc.add(new LongPoint("modified", lastModified));

      // Add the contents of the file to a field named "contents".  Specify a Reader,
      // so that the text of the file is tokenized and indexed, but not stored.
      // Note that FileReader expects the file to be in UTF-8 encoding.
      // If that's not the case searching for special characters will fail.
      // WE READ AND STORE FILE IN DATA BEFORE STORING
      BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
      String strLine;
      String contentData="";
      // Now lets loop
      while((strLine=br.readLine())!=null){
          // Now lets now
          contentData+="\n"+strLine;
      }
      // Now lets read line of content

      doc.add(new TextField("contents", contentData, Field.Store.YES));

      /************ HERE WE TRY TO ADD A UNIQUE FIELDS SENT THROUGH THE XFIELD IF XFIELD IS
       *  NOT NULL AND WE MAKE IT ALL A TEXTFIELD FIELD TYPE
       */
      if(fields!=null){
        // THEN WE ARE TO CREATE DYNAMIC FIELDS
        // Lets process the stream data
          BufferedReader fileData=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
          // LETS CHECK THE DOCTYPE VARIABLE
          if(docType.equals(new String("arrayFile"))){
              /******** We process as an array file to add fields ******/
              // Now lets try to convert file data to array again
              while((data=fileData.readLine())!=null){
                  // NOW LETS READ FILE DATA TO CONVERT TO ARRAY
                  Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("([^<]+)?(<as:(.*?)s>)?");
                  // Calling the matcher
                    Matcher m = pat.matcher(data);

                    while (m.find()) {
                        String contents = m.group(1);
                        String prefix = m.group(3);

                        if (prefix != null) { prefixList.add(prefix); }
                        if (contents != null) { contentList.add(contents); }
                    } // End of while loop

             /********* NOW LETS COMPOSE INTO AN ARRAY ***************/
                contentArray=new String[contentList.size()];
                prefixArray=new String[prefixList.size()];
                // Now lets compose to array
                contentArray=contentList.toArray(contentArray);
                prefixArray=prefixList.toArray(prefixArray);

              } // End of while loop

              /************ NOW WE CAN CREATE DYNAMIC FIELDS *************/

              // Checking
              if(field.isFile()){
                  // We read the field file to get all the fields
                  fin=Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fields), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
                  // Now lets get file data line by line
                  fLine=fin.readLine();
                  /******* Now we can process the field data *****/
                  fieldArray=fLine.split(";");
                  // Lets check count
                  if(fieldArray.length>0){
                      // We keep processing
                      meta=fieldArray[0];
                      ffields=fieldArray[1];
                      // Now lets validate the field data file
                      // We get the meta type
                      metaData=meta.split(",");
                      // Now lets get type
                      metaType=metaData[1];
                      // Now lets get the type value fieldValidType
                      typeSplit=metaType.split("-");
                     // NOW LETS CHECK IF TYPE IS IN ARRAY
                      typeVal=typeSplit[1];

                      /********* Now lets check if type exists in array **********/
                      if(Arrays.asList(fieldValidType).contains(typeVal)){
                          // ARRAY CONTAINS TYPE SO LETS PROCEED
                          String[] fieldsData=ffields.split(":");
                          // We further split fields data by comma
                          String fDatas=fieldsData[1];
                          // Further split
                          String[] fd=fDatas.split(",");
                          /***** Lets loop field array create the fields ******/
                          if(fd.length>0){
                            for(int i=0; i<=fd.length; i++){
                                /*********** We do a bit inner loop to check if field matches *********/
                                for(String prefix:prefixArray){
                                // Now lets check before we create
                                    if(fd[i]==prefix){ // We create appropriately
                                // NOW LET US CREATE INDIVIDUAL FIELDS FROM ARRAY LOOP
                                Field dynamicField = new TextField(fd[i], contentArray[i], Field.Store.YES);
                                doc.add(dynamicField);
                                    } // End of if
                                } // End of foreach loop
                            } // End of loop
                          } // End of check
                      }
                      else{
                          // WHEN TYPE DOESNT EXIST WE LOG MESSAGE
                          // Just do nothing here
                      }

                  }

              }
              else{
                  // We assume that field is a string so we process as a string
                  // WE PROCESS FIELD STRING TO GET VALUES
                  int fieldIndex=fields.indexOf("*"); // Setting index value
                  if(fieldIndex>=0){
                  // Now lets split
                  fieldArray=fields.split("\\*");
                  // Lets check count and loop
                  if(fieldArray.length>0){
                      // We loop individual fields
                      for(int i=0; i<=fieldArray.length; i++){
                          // Now lets further process
                          /*********** We do a bit inner loop to check if field matches *********/
                            for(String prefix:prefixArray){
                            // Now lets check before we create
                                if(fieldArray[i]==prefix){ // We create appropriately
                            // NOW LET US CREATE INDIVIDUAL FIELDS FROM ARRAY LOOP
                            Field dynamicField = new TextField(fieldArray[i], contentArray[i], Field.Store.YES);
                            doc.add(dynamicField);
                                } // End of if
                            } // End of foreach loop
                      } // End of for loop
                  } // End of count check
                  }
                  else{
                      // Setting a counter
                      int counter=0;
                    // We handle the values straight without loop
                      for(String prefix:prefixArray){
                            // Now lets check before we create
                            if(fields==prefix){ // We create appropriately
                            // NOW LET US CREATE INDIVIDUAL FIELDS FROM ARRAY LOOP
                            Field dynamicField = new TextField(fields, contentArray[counter], Field.Store.YES);
                            doc.add(dynamicField);
                            counter++; // Increment counter
                                } // End of if
                            } // End of foreach loop  
                  }
              }

          }
          else if(docType.equals(new String("normalFile"))){
              /******** We process as a normal file to add fields ******/
              // WE PROCESS FILE TO GET EACH LINES
            // Now lets try to convert file data to array again
              while((data=fileData.readLine())!=null){
            // We check if there there  
                  fieldAdder(data, doc, fields);
              } // end of while loop
          }
      }

      if (writer.getConfig().getOpenMode() == OpenMode.CREATE) {
        // New index, so we just add the document (no old document can be there):
        // System.out.println("adding " + file);
        writer.addDocument(doc);
      } else {
        // Existing index (an old copy of this document may have been indexed) so 
        // we use updateDocument instead to replace the old one matching the exact 
        // path, if present:
        // System.out.println("updating " + file);
        writer.updateDocument(new Term("path", file.toString()), doc);
      }
    }
  }

  /** CREATING A METHOD FOR CREATING DYNAMIC FIELDS **/
  private static void fieldAdder(String fileContent, Document doc, String fields){
    /************* CREATING VARIABLES FOR THIS METHOD *******************/
      try{
      // Other variable parts
      String[] fieldArray;
      String[] fieldValidType={"pdf", "xml", "html"};
      BufferedReader fin = null;
      String fLine="";

      // Checking if field is string of a file
      File field=new File(fields);
      String meta="";
      String metaType="";
      String typeVal="";
      String[] metaData;
      String[] typeSplit;
      String ffields="";
      int indexOnContent=0;

    // Checking
      if(field.isFile()){
          // We read the field file to get all the fields
          fin=Files.newBufferedReader(Paths.get(fields), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
          // Now lets get file data line by line
          fLine=fin.readLine();
          /******* Now we can process the field data *****/
          fieldArray=fLine.split(";");
          // Lets check count
          if(fieldArray.length>0){
              // We keep processing
              meta=fieldArray[0];
              ffields=fieldArray[1];
              // Now lets validate the field data file
              // We get the meta type
              metaData=meta.split(",");
              // Now lets get type
              metaType=metaData[1];
              // Now lets get the type value fieldValidType
              typeSplit=metaType.split("-");
             // NOW LETS CHECK IF TYPE IS IN ARRAY
              typeVal=typeSplit[1];

              /********* Now lets check if type exists in array **********/
              if(Arrays.asList(fieldValidType).contains(typeVal)){
                  // ARRAY CONTAINS TYPE SO LETS PROCEED
                  String[] fieldsData=ffields.split(":");
                  // We further split fields data by comma
                  String fDatas=fieldsData[1];
                  // Further split
                  String[] fd=fDatas.split(",");
                  /***** Lets loop field array create the fields ******/
                  if(fd.length>0){
                    for(int i=0; i<=fd.length; i++){
                        /*********** Check if index exist *********/
                        indexOnContent=fileContent.indexOf(fd[i]);
                        // Now lets check before we create
                            if(indexOnContent>0){ // We create appropriately
                        // NOW LET US CREATE INDIVIDUAL FIELDS FROM ARRAY LOOP
                        Field dynamicField = new TextField(fd[i], fileContent, Field.Store.YES);
                        doc.add(dynamicField);
                            } // End of if
                    } // End of loop
                  } // End of check
              }
              else{
                  // WHEN TYPE DOESNT EXIST WE LOG MESSAGE
                  // Just do nothing here
              }

          }

      }
      else{
          // We assume that field is a string so we process as a string
          // WE PROCESS FIELD STRING TO GET VALUES
          int fieldIndex=fields.indexOf("*"); // Setting index value
          if(fieldIndex>0){
          // Now lets split
          fieldArray=fields.split("\\*");
          // Lets check count and loop
          if(fieldArray.length>0){
              // We loop individual fields
              for(int i=0; i<=((fieldArray.length)-1); i++){
                  // Now lets further process
                  /*********** Check if index exist *********/
                    indexOnContent=fileContent.indexOf(fieldArray[i]);
                    // Now lets check before we create
                    if(indexOnContent>=0){ // We create appropriately
                    // NOW LET US CREATE INDIVIDUAL FIELDS FROM ARRAY LOOP
                    Field dynamicField = new TextField(fieldArray[i], fileContent, Field.Store.YES);
                    doc.add(dynamicField);
                        } // End of if
              } // End of for loop
          } // End of count check
          }
          else{
            // We handle the values straight without loop
              indexOnContent=fileContent.indexOf(fields);
                // Now lets check before we create
                if(indexOnContent>0){ // We create appropriately
                    // NOW LET US CREATE INDIVIDUAL FIELDS FROM ARRAY LOOP
                    Field dynamicField = new TextField(fields, fileContent, Field.Store.YES);
                    doc.add(dynamicField);
                        } // End of if  
          }
      }
      } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
      // END OF METHOD
  }

  // END OF CLASS
}
```

After indexing i find `writer.lock` file in my index directory. I dont know if its the cause of the problem.

Everything seems ok. I just dont know what could be the cause of the zero hits.

Comment: Your code is really long and I don't know what you're doing. It's also not clear where and how you use the class `IndexFiles`. And where do you search for documents? How to you get the writer object from the class? I don't see any getter method.

Comment: And the `write.lock` file is closed once you close the application. See https://lucene.apache.org/core/2_9_4/fileformats.html#Lock%20File If something crashed due to exceptions, than a process might be still running and has to be terminated.

Comment: I've started finding document with the searchFile class but am not getting totalhits. The total hits is zero but am getting documents. Why is this happening?

Comment: To be honest, you should open a new question if something does not work. This here is getting too chaotic. And the original question was already answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The error message shows you exactly the line in the code where the `NullPointerException` occurs. And you're the only one that has the full code and with line numbers...
2. Nevertheless, it's quite obvious that you forgot to initialize the array in your method `searchFetched`
3. I do not understand why you want to create a new array containing the same objects
4. In Java you can clone arrays using `clone()` or copy it `Arrays.copyOf(T[], int)`

Comment: can you give me an example code of the clone, Array.copyOf

Comment: Hm, it's still not clear why you have to create a new array. `hits.topDocs` already returns an array of `ScoreDoc` so why do you need to copy it? Anyways, `Arrays.copyOf(hits.topDocs, hits.topDocs.length)`

Comment: I have edited it to this private ScoreDoc[] searchFetched(TopDocs hits) throws IOException, Exception{
  // Lets set the array to hold our scores
  
  // NOW LETS RETURN SCORES
  return hits.scoreDocs;
 }

Comment: I need to return the data the search found with a public method so i can call it from my other applications and use it

Comment: What means "still not working"? Do you get another error?

Comment: Ok, but what is in line 228?  As I said, I don't have the full code, thus, I cannot check for line numbers.

Comment: for(Document row:rows){
                    // Now we make use of scoreDoc
                    System.out.println("File: " +row.get("path"));
                } // End of loop

Comment: This is in the main method i posted with the question

Comment: Ah, ok. But this is basically the same mistake that you made. Just also in the other method `resultSet` . here again you initialized the array with null: `Document[] resultSet=null;` and then you tried to add elements to it - how should that work?

Comment: How can i initialize? cause i want to return it

Comment: Am not getting output from the 'resultSet' method, maybe thats the problem

Comment: You should know how to create an array in Java. Indeed you have to know the size in advance which is obviously the length of the `searched` array.

Comment: Now i can successfully index document but cant get hits in search. I found a file called writer.lock, maybe it causing the problem. Am no more getting errors, i just cant get a hit even when documents are indexed successfully.

Comment: sorry, but that's too vague. Nor is it clear whether the index really contains documents, nor whether the query is used correctly. By the way, have you tried one of the tutorials first?

Comment: Why am saying it indexes successful is that it create index files in the index directory